# Angular two modules with the same path

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have two modules in my app: **HomeModule** and **LoginModule**. 
I want to be able to load two different modules in the same path. Which module loads depends on if the user is logged in or not.  
If user is logged in, **HomeModule** should load for him, if not - **LoginModule** should load.

I tried this code, there is no error in the console, **HomeModule** loads if user is logged in, but if the user is not logged in - nothing loads. If I reverse the order of my routes, **LoginModule** works and **HomeModule** doesn't.
 **HomeGuard**.canLoad() returns true if user is logged in, **LoginGuard**.canLoad() returns true if the user is not logged in.

**HomeGuard**.canLoad:

```js
if (this.userSessionService.userSession) {
    return true;
}
this.router.navigate(['./']);
return false;
```

**LoginGuard**.canLoad:

```js
if (this.userSessionService.userSession) {
    this.router.navigate(['./']);
    return false;
}
return true;
```

My routing:

```js
{ path: '', loadChildren: './home/index#HomeModule', canLoad: [HomeGuard] },
{ path: '', loadChildren: './login/index#LoginModule', canLoad: [LoginGuard]}
```

It should work like the main route in the Facebook web app. If I go to *facebook.com* I see login page if I am not logged in, if I am logged in I see app as logged user.

Answer (score 3):

The `canLoad` stops the children from loading, but doesn't prevent the parent from matching the route.

You could try using a URL [matcher](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher) instead. The only problem here is that the matcher is just a function. You would want to return `true` or `false` based upon the state in a service. As a temporary approach you could try a global variable as a flag to see if using a matcher will help.

If the matcher works, then I would wrap the routes in a parent route with a resolver. The resolver would assign the user state to a global variable which was used by the matcher.

```
 {
    path: '',
    resolver: { ignore: ResolveUserStateForMatcher },
    children: [
         { matcher: MatchHomeRoute, loadChildren: './home/index#HomeModule' },
         { matcher: MatchLoginRoute, loadChildren: './login/index#LoginModule' }
    ]
 }
```

The point here is that the matcher prevents the Router from executing any logic for the `HomeModule` when a user is logged in. Which is the same as not loading the module.

I'm not sure what the MatchResult should be for these.